# Cannot view option value html(data)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to show my select option value with **Ajax jQuery**
here is

**JS:**

```
$('#jenis_jab').change(function(){
      var jab = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $.ajax({
          url   : 'proses/ajax_process.php?aksi=jenis_jab',
          type  : 'POST',
          data  : 'jab=' + jab,
          dataType: 'text',
          success:function(data) {
            $('#uk').html(data);
          }
        });
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset( $_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi']=='jenis_jab') {
    $jab    = $_POST['jab'];
    $sql    = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_unit_kerja WHERE jabatan='$jab'");
    while($data = $sql->fetch_array()) {
    echo "<option value=$data[id]>$data[unit_kerja]</option>";
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="uk"></select>
```

**I use materializecss**

this is work for html div, but for option value is not working

what's wrong?

thanks

Comment: Can you show your html? Is the issue getting the value of the selected option or displaying the values from the db? You're question isn't clear. Also, your query is open to sql injection, use params whenever using user/browser supplied data. Always using them is even better practice.

Comment: <select id="uk"></select>

i use materialize css

Comment: Try to remove the single quotation from your select statement.

Answer (score 0):

sorry it's done with

```
$('#uk').change(function(){
      var uk = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        $.ajax({
          url   : 'proses/ajax_process.php?aksi=unit_kerja',
          type  : 'POST',
          data  : 'uk=' + uk,
          dataType: 'text',
          success:function(data) {
            $('#suk').html(data);
            $('#suk').material_select();
          }
        });
    });
```